# OnCompletion mediaPlayer does not change image resource

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, imagebutton

I'm trying to change the resource assigned to `ImageButton` once mediaPlayer finished playing audio. This is my code, but id does not work:

```
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        play.invalidate();

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);

                if(isPlaying){  
                        mMediaPlayer.stop();  
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                        mMediaPlayer = null;
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        play.invalidate();
                        isPlaying = false;
                }
                else{
                    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, songs[position]);                
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    isPlaying = true;
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                    play.invalidate();

                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            isPlaying = false;

                            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                            play.invalidate();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: nothing works for me. Are you able to find solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to request the layout first :

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            isPlaying = false;

                            play.requestLayout(); //call this
                            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                            play.invalidate();
                        }
```

If it still not working, try to change this code

```
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
```

To :

```
play.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.play));
```

Or if you still want to use setImageResource :

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(R.drawable.play, "drawable", getPackageName());
play.setImageResource(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
         ...
```

you should have:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        ...
```